# Iterating through a multidimensional array in a specific way

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array with shape `(1000, 4, 200)`

```
import numpy as np 
array = np.ndarray((1000, 4, 200), dtype=int)
```

`4` is used to represent the number of channels, `200` is used to represent the number of samples, and 1000 is used to represent, well.. the time domain (not sure how to put it)

How do I iterate through this array in a specific order such that inside a for loop when I print the shape of my array, for each of 200 samples, it must print,

```
SAMPLE: 1 
(1000, ) #Channel1
(1000, ) #Channel2
(1000, ) #Channel3
(1000, ) #Channel4

SAMPLE: 2 
(1000, ) #Channel1
(1000, ) #Channel2
(1000, ) #Channel3
(1000, ) #Channel4

SAMPLE: 3 
(1000, ) #Channel1
(1000, ) #Channel2
(1000, ) #Channel3
(1000, ) #Channel4
.
.
.
SAMPLE: 200 
(1000, ) #Channel1
(1000, ) #Channel2
(1000, ) #Channel3
(1000, ) #Channel4
```

It's not so much that my print statement should be exact, I just want to be able to extract each channel one after another with the time domain as a column vector..

What did I try?

Well.. I haven't done anything special, I simply have a nested loop that does through each dimension from left to right and that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually VERY simple: Just use transpose..

```
array = array.T
for row in array:
    for channel in row:
        print(channel.shape)
    print()
```